# Validating forms with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, validation, innerhtml

I am trying to validate a form without displaying the error message as an alert. innerHTML seems to be my best bet.

I have tried to implement it but I'm having no luck.

Here is the code.

Javascript:

```
    <script> function validateForm() {
            var x = "";
            if (document.orderForm.firstName.value = "")
            x += "Please enter your first name.";
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = x;
            return false;
            }</script>
```

HTML:

```
     <form name="orderForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="processForm.html" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Personal Information</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" size="30"></td>

        </tr>
        </table>
    <div name="error" id="error"> 
    </div>
   </form>
```

Right now no error message is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script> function validateForm() {
        if (document.orderForm.firstName.value == ""){ // == is comparison... = is assignment
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Please enter your first name.";
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true //Don't forget to return true if everything checks out
        }</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`if (document.orderForm.firstName.value = "")` **assigns** the value `""` to `document.orderForm.firstName.value`, then evaluates as a *false* value, so the `if` statement will never be true.

Use a comparison, not an assignment. `==`.

---

While you are at it, please learn about [validators](http://validator.w3.org), [labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible), and [CSS](https://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<input  type="text" id="Ifname">
<div id="fname"></div>
<button type="submit" onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
</body>
```

for a div having id="xyz" and will show the error for getting an input

field id="abc"

the function will call on the submit of button having onclick="validate()"

```
function validate(){
     var x = "";
     if (document.getElementById('Ifname').value == "")
    {
    document.getElementById('fname').innerHTML = "Email is Required!";
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    return true;
    }
    }

    </script>
</html>
```

Please use this code to check validation for for 1 button.